# Can't refresh image in webView - mac project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, caching

I'm using `WebView` in my mac project and using below code for load URL.

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:10];    
[[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

Dynamically replace image in same image name in document path. Here i reload `WebView` and it will not changed current image. Instead it showing previous cached image.

Please help me how to reload current image in my `WebView`